# Flutter - setState() isn't updating the button's text color?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, state

The problem is, whenever I click on the Like button, the color isn't changing for the button icon and the text as I am updating on onPressed() method. What could be the issue, please guide? I am experimenting with flutter from the last 1 month.

This is my class code:

```
class SingelBattleAllComments extends StatefulWidget {
  final int battleId; // add info

  SingelBattleAllComments({@required this.battleId});

  @override
  _SingelBattleAllCommentsState createState() =>
      _SingelBattleAllCommentsState(battleId: battleId);
}

class _SingelBattleAllCommentsState extends State<SingelBattleAllComments> {
  final int battleId; // add info

  final List<String> profileImages = [
    'https://www.codecyan.com/images/omi-shah-codecyan-founder-ceo.jpg'];

  Color likeButtonColor;
  List<Widget> commentsListItems;

  _SingelBattleAllCommentsState({@required this.battleId});

  @override
  void initState() {
    likeButtonColor = new Color(0xff333030);

    commentsListItems = List<Widget>.generate(5, (i) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                  child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                imageUrl: profileImages[0

                                    ],
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50)),
                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text("OMi Shah",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  )),
                              SizedBox(height: 3),
                              Container(
                                width: 250, //screenWidth * 0.65,
                                child: Text(
                                  "Hello",
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  FlatButton.icon(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        likeButtonColor = Colors.red;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    label: Text("Like (291)",
                                        style:
                                            TextStyle(color: likeButtonColor)),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up,
                                        color: likeButtonColor),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 15),
                                  FlatButton.icon(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    label: Text("Report",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: const Color(0xff333030))),
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.report,
                                        color: const Color(0xff333030)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ])
                      ])))
        ],
      );
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 10),
              itemCount: commentsListItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                return commentsListItems[index];
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

This is the output screenshot:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you putting all of your code in initState?

Comment: I have put in initState() to populate some demo data? did I do wrong?

Comment: Actually `setState` works (try to add `commentsListItems.removeLast();` inside `setState`), this will works. I think when you use List.generate and return Column, likeButtonColor is no longer referenced. So: **Its not about setState, its about your list<widget> usage**

Comment: @IbrahimKarahan actually, you're right. But, I can't figure out why color isn't updating :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can create only one widget and bind those data into this widget

code snippet

```
 commentsListItems = List<int>.generate(5, (i) => i + 1);
 ...
 Widget Comment(int index) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 15),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SingelBattleAllComments(battleId: 1,),
    );
  }
}

class SingelBattleAllComments extends StatefulWidget {
  final int battleId; // add info

  SingelBattleAllComments({@required this.battleId});

  @override
  _SingelBattleAllCommentsState createState() =>
      _SingelBattleAllCommentsState(battleId: battleId);
}

class _SingelBattleAllCommentsState extends State<SingelBattleAllComments> {
  final int battleId; // add info

  final List<String> profileImages = [
    'https://www.codecyan.com/images/omi-shah-codecyan-founder-ceo.jpg'
  ];

  Color likeButtonColor;
  List<int> commentsListItems;

  _SingelBattleAllCommentsState({@required this.battleId});

  @override
  void initState() {
    likeButtonColor = Color(0xff333030);
    commentsListItems = List<int>.generate(5, (i) => i + 1);
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget Comment(int index) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 15),
        Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            imageUrl: profileImages[0

                            ],
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("OMi Shah",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                )),
                            SizedBox(height: 3),
                            Container(
                              width: 250, //screenWidth * 0.65,
                              child: Text(
                                "Hello",
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                FlatButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      likeButtonColor = Colors.red;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  label: Text("Like (291)",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: likeButtonColor)),
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up,
                                      color: likeButtonColor),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 15),
                                FlatButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  label: Text("Report",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: const Color(0xff333030))),
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.report,
                                      color: const Color(0xff333030)),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ])
                    ])))
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 10),
          itemCount: commentsListItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
            return Comment(index);
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setState() method notifies the framework that the internal state of the Stateful widget has changed. Calling this method is what triggers the widget to rebuild with the latest state values, So put all your code in build method and it will work